# Let $K$ be a field, $A \subset K$, and $p \subset A$. Then $\exists$ a valuation ring $R$ satistfying...

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I was stuck when reading a proof of the following theorem (Matsumura p. 72-3, Theorem 10.2),

> Let $K$ be a field, $A \subset K$ a subring, and $p$ a prime ideal of $A$. Then there exists a valuation ring $R$ of $K$ satisfying
>
> $$A \subset R \space \text{and} \space m_{R} \cap A = p$$ where $m_{R}$ is the maximal ideal of $R$.

There are two parts to the proof. The first part proves that there is a **largest** possible subring $R$ of $K$ with $A \subset R \space \text{and} \space m_{R} \cap A = p$.

The second part proves that $R$ is a valuation ring of $K$. Now let $x \in K$ and $x \not\in R$. Suppose that $1 \in pR[x]$. Then there exists a relation of the form

$$1 = a_0 + a_1x+ ... + a_nx^n \space \text{with} \space a_i \in pR \space \space \space \space \space (1)$$

$1 - a_0$ is a unit of $R$, since $a_0 \in pR \subset m_R$. The proof says that this implies the existence of the following relation $$1 = b_1x + ... + b_nx^n \space \text{with} \space b_i \in m_R \space \space \space \space \space (2)$$

Of course, you can multiply by $(1)$ by the inverse of $1-a_0$ to get a relation like $(2)$. But why does it say that $b_i \in m_R$. Should we not also have $b_i \in pR$ (since $pR$ is also an ideal).

Comment: It seems like $pR \subset m_R$ so that in fact we do also have $b_i \in pR$ (but presumably Matsumura does not need this to get the contradiction).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathfrak p= \mathfrak m_R\cap A \subset  \mathfrak m_R$, hence $\mathfrak p R\subset  \mathfrak m_R$ and finally $b_i=(1-a_0)^{-1}a_i\in  \mathfrak m_R$.

Comment: Thanks. I just thought there was something I was missing since he made the transition from $pR$ in (1) to $m$ in (2).